# Detect If New Line Is Started In Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I was just wondering if there is a way to detect if a new line(hitting enter to start a new row) can be detected in an equation and then create another blank row as to give space between two items. Also I would like it to do a command on the blank line. If this is possible please let me know as it will complete my project.

Comment: If this help anyone I'll explain what I'm trying to accomplish in simpler terms here. I am basically wondering if I can have a formula create a new row?

Comment: Could you please edit your clarification into your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to insert a line break into a formula or text. Line breaks in formulas are effectively ignored unless they appear inside a text string so you can't use line breaks to enter multiple formulas in a single cell.